# my nivo slider in wordpress dont showing arrows and navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, nivo-slider

hi after integrating the nivo slider in my wordpress the images are sliding perfectly with given animation. but the arrow images for prev and next is not showing.instead it shows

```
prev and next
```

in the slider. also instead of navigation bullets it shows numbers as `1234` , that navigate according to the images. in which file should i change to solve the problem?

the nivoslider.css is

```
.nivoSlider {
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
overflow: hidden;
}
 .nivoSlider img {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
max-width: none;
}
 .nivo-main-image {
display: block !important;
position: relative !important; 
width: 100% !important;
 }

  /* If an image is wrapped in a link */
   .nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink {
position:absolute;
top:0px;
left:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:0;
padding:0;
margin:0;
z-index:6;
display:none;
background:white; 
filter:alpha(opacity=0); 
opacity:0;
   }
  /* The slices and boxes in the Slider */
   .nivo-slice {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
height:100%;
top:0;
    }
    .nivo-box {
display:block;
position:absolute;
z-index:5;
overflow:hidden;
    }
    .nivo-box img { display:block; }

     /* Caption styles */
     .nivo-caption {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
background:#000;
color:#fff;
width:100%;
z-index:8;
padding: 5px 10px;
opacity: 0.8;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
-moz-opacity: 0.8;
filter:alpha(opacity=8);
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
        }
     .nivo-caption p {
padding:5px;
margin:0;
       }
      .nivo-caption a {
display:inline !important;
        }
       .nivo-html-caption {
         display:none;
        }
        /* Direction nav styles (e.g. Next & Prev) */
      .nivo-directionNav a {
position:absolute;
top:45%;
z-index:9;
cursor:pointer;
       }
     .nivo-prevNav {
left:0px;
        }
       .nivo-nextNav {
right:0px;
       }
    /* Control nav styles (e.g. 1,2,3...) */
     .nivo-controlNav {
text-align:center;
padding: 15px 0;
    }
      .nivo-controlNav a {
cursor:pointer;
    }
   .nivo-controlNav a.active {
font-weight:bold;
     }
```

**EDIT::**

i found out the problem. its my mistake. sorry to all. i forgot to give `get_template_directory_uri()` in href.when i gave that arrows and bullets works perfectly. this question is **resolved**.

Comment: might be prev,next icon path is wrong

Comment: in the default css file the url is given like background:url('arrows.png'); is it correct?? bcz the default.css file is stored in the same folder as arrows.png stored.

Comment: ok then paste your code in fiddle we will check

Comment: but sir its a wordpress file which of the files i should paste. there are so many

Comment: url to the image in css may wrong.check the css for pre and next

Comment: the picture is in var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/images/. so should i give like background:url('the whole path/arrow.png') or just url('images/arrow.png') ??

Answer (score 0):

`prev` and `next` have CSS classes and background-images you should in your file

The Example CSS

```
.nivo-directionNav a {
    background: url("images/arrows.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 0 none;
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 30px;
}
```